# Is there an XML Schema 1.0 datatype for [the names of] all XML Schema 1.0 datatypes?

Tags: xml, types, xsd, xml-validation, xsd-1.0

By XML Schema datatype, I mean any datatype that would be found in the schema for schemas.

Does anyone know of such a type? [That is, a type which accepts the names of the XSD 1.0 datatypes, and nothing else.]

#### Edit: Example:

XML:

```
<table name="my_name">
    <column name="col1" type="BOOLEAN">
    <column name="col2" type="INT"/>
</table>
```

So the goal is the validate the `type` attribute for element `column`. The type attribute would ideally validate only valid XML datatypes, such as int, boolean, or string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you haven't expressed yourself clearly: I suspect that what you want is a type whose value space is the set of names of built-in simple types.

The names of built-in simple types are all QNames, so your type should be a restriction of xs:QName, restricted with an enumeration to constrain it to the built-in types:

```
<xs:simpleType name="builtInTypeName">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:QName">
    <xs:enumeration value="xs:decimal"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="xs:boolean"/>
    etc
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

At least, I think that's what you want - but I'm guessing. The fact that you haven't used the XSD type names like xs:boolean and xs:integer, but your own type names BOOLEAN and INT, makes me suspect I haven't quite grasped what you are after.

Comment: This is very close to what I want. I'm not sure yet whether I can alter the xml so that the type names match QName. Yes, I was a bit unclear, I'm still acclimating to the jargon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `xs:anyType`, or maybe `xs:anySimpleType`.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I basically want a specific subset of string, so that the value field for an xml element of this type can accept only values that are datatypes. Clarifying this by example in the edit in my post.

Comment: Yes, xs:anySimpleType is exactly what you say you are looking for; its lexical space is the union of the lexical spaces of all simple types defined by the XSD spec.  If you have your heart set on a subset of string that matches all built-in types, then xs:string itself will do the trick.  (No proper subset will satisfy the requirement that it match all valid datatypes, since xs:string is itself a datatype.)  If you want to match just a particular set of the built-in types,  and not all of them, then make a union of the types you want to match.

Comment: I'll just go with string. Neither are exactly what I would like ("int" or "boolean" validates, but so does asdfasdf), but they work.

Comment: So you want `1234` and `true` and `asdfasdf` to validate. Do you want `asdf asdf` to validate? Do you want `2013-06-19 09:31` to validate? What do you want to have _not_ validate?

Comment: Here are some more examples of values for "type" (see xml above) that I'd like to validate:  string, int, float, boolean. Things that shouldn't validate: asdf, 2013-06-19, Truth, yesterday, 12:48. Does that help? I may end up using a simple regex...but the idea is for any datatype name to validate.